# I am trying to compare two DateTime Objects in JavaScript and it is giving me a wrong answers

Tags: javascript

I am comapring a recorded datetime object with the current date( generated by Date() function and the result is not as expected.

```
var  apptTime = "2018.01.26.08.30.10.00";
var checkinTime = "2018.01.26.09.45.10.00";

var yappt = apptTime.substring(0,4);
var mappt = apptTime.substring(5,7); 
var dappt = apptTime.substring(8,10);
var hrappt = apptTime.substring(11,13);
var mmappt = apptTime.substring(14,16);
var ssappt = apptTime.substring(17,19);
var msappt = apptTime.substring(20,22);

var ycht = checkinTime.substring(0,4);
var mcht = checkinTime.substring(5,7);
var dcht = checkinTime.substring(8,10);
var hrcht = checkinTime.substring(11,13);
var mmcht = checkinTime.substring(14,16);
var sscht = checkinTime.substring(17,19);
var mscht = checkinTime.substring(20,22);

var newapptTime = new Date(yappt,mappt,dappt,hrappt,mmappt,ssappt,msappt);
var newcheckinTime = new Date(ycht, mcht, dcht, hrcht, mmcht, sscht, mscht);
var currTime =  new Date();

alert(currTime.getTime() > newcheckinTime.getTime());
```

Giving answer as False , while the current time is 4:10 pm.!!!!

Comment: not sure why you are parsing the date and time like that use some library like momentjs

Comment: Probably it's because the month-parameter is 0-based (January is 0): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Missing a `parseInt`? Why not make the datetime format in a parseable format? You could think about using momentjs as well

Comment: The least you can do is to use `split(".")`

Answer (score 0):

Your `newcheckinTime` date variable was not created properly.

In creating `var newcheckinTime = new Date(year, month, ...)` the month is zero based, January should = 0. And your string extraction month is '1' based.

try:

```
var mcht = checkinTime.substring(5,7); // unchanged existing line.
mcht = mcht -1;// new line to adjust the month.
```

and again:

```
var mappt = apptTime.substring(5,7); // existing
mappt = mappt -1;// new line
```

Edit: (added full code)

```js
var  apptTime = "2018.01.26.08.30.10.00";
var checkinTime = "2018.01.26.09.45.10.00";

var yappt = apptTime.substring(0,4);
var mappt = apptTime.substring(5,7); 
    mappt = mappt -1;                // new line to adjust the month.
var dappt = apptTime.substring(8,10);
var hrappt = apptTime.substring(11,13);
var mmappt = apptTime.substring(14,16);
var ssappt = apptTime.substring(17,19);
var msappt = apptTime.substring(20,22);

var ycht = checkinTime.substring(0,4);
var mcht = checkinTime.substring(5,7);
    mcht = mcht -1;                 // new line to adjust the month.
var dcht = checkinTime.substring(8,10);
var hrcht = checkinTime.substring(11,13);
var mmcht = checkinTime.substring(14,16);
var sscht = checkinTime.substring(17,19);
var mscht = checkinTime.substring(20,22);

var newapptTime = new Date(yappt,mappt,dappt,hrappt,mmappt,ssappt,msappt);
var newcheckinTime = new Date(ycht, mcht, dcht, hrcht, mmcht, sscht, mscht);
var currTime =  new Date();

console.log("currTime: ", currTime);
console.log("newcheckinTime: ", newcheckinTime);
console.log("Is currTime > newcheckinTime : ", currTime.getTime() > newcheckinTime.getTime());
```

@Sammy's answer looks simpler though. :)

Happy Coding! Gary.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @gforce301 It answered the question by fixing the bug in the code. But I've edited to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little confused about what the function `geTime` returns.

## [`Date.prototype.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

> The getTime() method returns the numeric value corresponding to the time for the specified date according to universal time.
>
> `getTime()` always uses UTC for time representation. For example, a client browser in one timezone, getTime() will be the same as a client browser in any other timezone.
>
> You can use this method to help assign a date and time to another Date object. This method is functionally equivalent to the [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueof) method.

**Example from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org):**

```
var moonLanding = new Date('July 20, 69 00:20:18 GMT+00:00');

// milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00.000 GMT
console.log(moonLanding.getTime());
// expected output: -14254782000
```

So, `getTime` function returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.

What you're trying to accomplish is compare DateTime, in your case `hours:minutes`

The following code snippet converts the hours to minutes and sums the minutes of each Date object.

```js
var  apptTime = "2018.01.26.08.30.10.00";
var checkinTime = "2018.01.26.09.45.10.00";

var yappt = apptTime.substring(0,4);
var mappt = apptTime.substring(5,7); 
var dappt = apptTime.substring(8,10);
var hrappt = apptTime.substring(11,13);
var mmappt = apptTime.substring(14,16);
var ssappt = apptTime.substring(17,19);
var msappt = apptTime.substring(20,22);

var ycht = checkinTime.substring(0,4);
var mcht = checkinTime.substring(5,7);
var dcht = checkinTime.substring(8,10);
var hrcht = checkinTime.substring(11,13);
var mmcht = checkinTime.substring(14,16);
var sscht = checkinTime.substring(17,19);
var mscht = checkinTime.substring(20,22);

var newapptTime = new Date(yappt,mappt,dappt,hrappt,mmappt,ssappt,msappt);
var newcheckinTime = new Date(ycht, mcht, dcht, hrcht, mmcht, sscht, mscht);
var currTime =  new Date();

console.log(newcheckinTime);
console.log(currTime);

console.log((currTime.getHours() * 60 + currTime.getMinutes()) > (newcheckinTime.getHours() * 60 + newcheckinTime.getMinutes()));
```

Comment: Not sure if your assumption is correct. The alert was false because  the current time stamp of 4pm on the 26th Jan 2018 was compared against the time stamp for a few hours earlier, **one month later** - the OP failed to adjust months to be zero based when converting strings into Date objects. Naturally your suggestion will work to compare time of day irrespective of date.

Comment: Yeah, there is good info in this answer, but it has the same bug as the question does. (months are zero-base in new Date()).

Comment: @GaryL and @ traktor53 both are right.  I didn't realize.  However, the question it's a little confusing.  I hope this info helps anybody else.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I resolved this, I had to negate the month by -1 while conversion since the months start from 0 in JS.

Answer (score -2):

I guess that you can give the date string to the Date object, and then do the compare which I believe it will work:

```
var d1 = new Date('2018.01.26.08.30.10.00');
var d2 = new Date('2018.01.26.09.45.10.00');

var same = d1.getTime() === d2.getTime();
var notSame = d1.getTime() !== d2.getTime();
```

P.S. try to put them inside () in the alert. because sometimes the JavaScript treat them as a string.

If it did not work due to string format, then try to sub your month by one.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question either.